# Understanding the space of parameters in a covariance matrix of conditional expectations

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

Let $\{(Y_n, Z_n)\}_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}$ be a zero-mean jointly stationary Gaussian process where $Z$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ and $Y$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Here, $n$ runs over the integers and let $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(Y_m: m\leq n)$.

I define $X_{i,n} := \mathbb{E}[Z_{n+i}|\mathcal{F}_n],$ for integer $i>0$.

Let $$\mathbb{E}[X_{i,n}X_{j,n}] = \rho_{ij} v_i v_j$$ where $v_i^2$ is the variance of $X_{i,n}$ and $\rho_{ij}$ is the correlation between $X_{i,n}$ and $X_{j,n}$. We must have $\rho_{ii}=1$, $v_i,v_j>0$ and that the correlation matrix $\rho$ is positive semi-definite for any finite subset of indices. There is an additional constraint that $v_i\geq v_j$ for $i<j$ which can be derived by the towering property of conditional expectation which can be used to conclude that

$$X_{i,n+j-i} = X_{j,n} + Z_{i,j,n}$$

where $Z_{i,j,n}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$.

Now, note that for any positive integers $i,j,k,$ we have

$$\mathbb{E}[X_{i,n}X_{j,n+k}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{i,n}\mathbb{E}[X_{j,n+k}|\mathcal{F}_n]] = \mathbb{E}[X_{i,n}X_{j+k,n}] = \rho_{i,j+k}v_iv_{j+k}$$

Thus the covariance between any two $X$ variables is completely parametrized by $\rho$ and $v$.

Let $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{psd}}$ denote the set of $(\rho,v)$ parameters that lead to a positive semi-definite covariance matrix for any finite subset of $X$ variables.

Let $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{realizable}}$ denote the set of $(\rho,v)$ parameters that can be achieved by suitable stationary processes $(Y,Z)$.

My questions are:

1. Characterize $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{psd}}$. (In particular, I believe the constraints on $(\rho,v)$ described above are insufficient to characterize $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{psd}}$)
2. Characterize $\mathcal{S}_{\mathrm{realizable}}$.
3. Are they the same?

This seems like a somewhat basic question in the study of martingales, so any references that can help me understand these questions would be very helpful.